# CSS element is unclickable

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

I made up a button which must open up the menu in mobile version of the site with jQuery but it is not working in any way.
I did the new project just with this button and menu to debug and it works fine and also I can't find any difference between this code and the original one.

My brain hurts very much, please tell me why this button is not working and what should I do with it.
(I replaced poping menu with exploding just to see if the button works)

I'm using jQuery UI.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#menu-icon').click(function() {
    $('header').toggle('explode');
  });
});
```

```css
nav {
  margin-left: -35px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

#menu-icon {
  background: url(../img/mobile-menu.png) no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  width: 0px;
}

nav li {
  display: inline;
}

nav .left-nav {
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#login {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 0;
}

nav h3 {
  text-indent: -9999px;
}

nav h3:after {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  content: ' ';
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 1%;
}

nav h3 a {
  background: url(../img/cart.png) no-repeat;
  width: 48px;
  height: 44px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav h3 a:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

nav a {
  font-family: 'Cormorant Infant', serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: #0d0d0d;
  padding: 15px 5px;
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  nav {
    height: 90px;
  }
  nav ul {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  nav .left-nav {
    margin-top: -5px;
    visibility: visible;
    padding-top: 0;
  }
  nav #login {
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    font-size: 50px;
    padding: 40px 0;
    top: -35px;
    margin-right: 55px;
  }
  nav h3 a {
    left: -73px;
  }
  #menu-icon {
    width: 78px;
    height: 65px;
    display: block;
    left: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
  header h3 {
    text-indent: -9999px;
  }
  .news {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h3 id="menu-icon">
        <a href="#"></a>Меню</h3>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Прайслист</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Подбор букета</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Доставка</a></li>
          <div class="left-nav">
            <li>
              <h3>
                <a href="#"></a>Корзина</h3>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" id="login">Войти</a></li>
          </div>
        </ul>
        <ul class="mob-menu hidden">
          <li><a href="#">Прайслист</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Подбор букета</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Доставка</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="banner">
        <a href="#" id="left"></a>
        <!-- image replacement лучше сделать в css без картинки -->
        <a href="#" id="right"></a>
        <!-- image replacement -->
        <h1>Цветочный Дом Полины</h1>
        <ul>
          <li id=selected>
            <a href="#"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Please spend [more time researching](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/497418) before asking a question on SO. If you'd read the jQuery API you'd know that [`.toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) isn't the right function.

Comment: I've add .toggle just to see if the button is clickable.

Comment: Reread what I just wrote. Toggle is the wrong function. It doesn't do what you think it does. I even *linked* to the jQuery API so you could **read** what the `toggle` function does. It won't help you "see if the button is clickable", pick a different function.

Comment: Okay if I replace it with toggleClass (which is exactly what I want to do) it still not working. And if I replace #menu-icon with any other element, let's say, 'header', it will do exactly what I think it does when I click it.

Comment: The point is that's not the reason the button isn't working

Comment: Also I'm using jQuery UI if it is matters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is just that your `nav` is overlapping `#menu-icon`.

Since it is already positioned absolutely, you can make sure `#menu-icon` is clickable just by giving it a `z-index` higher than zero.

You are right that the function you use has nothing to do with it, but I went ahead and added jQuery UI to the snippet anyway, to alleviate any possible confusion about using the `.toggle()` method.

Note that I commented out your `left` and `text-indent` styles in the snippet below just to make sure it's clear at a glance what you're supposed to click, but that's not actually necessary to make `#menu-icon` clickable; you can still click its invisible box if you add those styles back in.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#menu-icon').click(function() {
    $('header').toggle('explode');
  });
});
```

```css
nav {
  margin-left: -35px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

#menu-icon {
  background: url(../img/mobile-menu.png) no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  /*left: -9999px;*/
  width: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}

nav li {
  display: inline;
}

nav .left-nav {
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#login {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 0;
}

/*nav h3 {
  text-indent: -9999px;
}*/

nav h3:after {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  content: ' ';
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 1%;
}

nav h3 a {
  background: url(../img/cart.png) no-repeat;
  width: 48px;
  height: 44px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav h3 a:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

nav a {
  font-family: 'Cormorant Infant', serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: #0d0d0d;
  padding: 15px 5px;
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  nav {
    height: 90px;
  }
  nav ul {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  nav .left-nav {
    margin-top: -5px;
    visibility: visible;
    padding-top: 0;
  }
  nav #login {
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    font-size: 50px;
    padding: 40px 0;
    top: -35px;
    margin-right: 55px;
  }
  nav h3 a {
    left: -73px;
  }
  #menu-icon {
    width: 78px;
    height: 65px;
    display: block;
    left: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
  /*header h3 {
    text-indent: -9999px;
  }*/
  .news {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <h3 id="menu-icon">
      <a href="#"></a>CLICK ME</h3>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Прайслист</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Подбор букета</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Доставка</a></li>
        <div class="left-nav">
          <li>
            <h3>
              <a href="#"></a>Корзина</h3>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" id="login">Войти</a></li>
        </div>
      </ul>
      <ul class="mob-menu hidden">
        <li><a href="#">Прайслист</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Подбор букета</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Доставка</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="banner">
      <a href="#" id="left"></a>
      <!-- image replacement лучше сделать в css без картинки -->
      <a href="#" id="right"></a>
      <!-- image replacement -->
      <h1>Цветочный Дом Полины</h1>
      <ul>
        <li id=selected>
          <a href="#"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Comment: I am very grateful for your help